# Is it possible to do a Git Commit with the user being the current SSH user?

Tags: git, ssh

Us in our team have our own SSH usernames that we use to log in to our dev server. When we do a git commit though (without specifying the author), the author of course becomes the **--global user.name** set.

But is it possible to automatically use the current SSH user as the git author? I can set a default global user.name for this. But the my purpose is so that when someone commits something from the dev server, we'll know right away who did it and not see something like *dev@oursite.com*. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible without each and every user setting their user.name manually on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least in a workaround, you can just commit with the author option

```
--author=<author>
```

and add an alias section to gitconfig

```
[alias]
  ci= !git commit --author="\"ENV_AUTHOR\""
```

if you now call

```
ENV_AUTHOR="a <b@c.d>" git ci
```

it will use the content of the variable `ENV_AUTHOR` as the author string. Now, you could fill this value in the login profile scripts for each user or do some magic with `whoami` and I don't know.